# korean language not displayed in android 4.2.2

Tags: android, localization

I am working on an app which needs to support korean language. But in emulator I can see nothing is being displayed when language is selected as korean. I have also found the same issue reported in following link https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=53844 .

Does anyone have solution for this issue. Please suggest.

Comment: looks like there is some issue with font. Not sure. But I have downloaded and added a custom font and its working.

Comment: Now the problem is I have to set this custom font for entire application only when language is selected as korean. There are many text fields in my app. Can someone suggest a solution for this please